# Error Adding a view in listview according to position or items

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter

```
if(position % 4 == 0)
{
    topic_lay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
}   
else  
{        
    topic_lay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

This is a code to make visible view in particular position but I want after 4th item in a list view should be visible.(as position starts from 0 which is conflict I want to add a view after 0,1,2,3-view-4,5,6,7-view-8,9,10,11-view- So on)

Comment: I think you can use a `ExpandableListView` to do this.

Comment: I want to add a Linear layout after 0,1,2,3 position to describe the data in the list it depends upon the 1,2, items .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Heading

```
if((position+1) % 4 == 0)
{    
   topic_lay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else
{   
   topic_lay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

0123 **4** 5678 **9** 10111213 **14** 15161718 **19** ...

You will display a view after 4th item so your first view position will start from 4 and each view separate by 5

```
if((position+1) % 5 == 0){    
   topic_lay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
   topic_lay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: it makes view visible after 5 th position  like 0,1,23,4 -view-5,6,7,8,9-view and I want to add a view 0,1,2,3-view -4,5,6,7-view-8,9,10,11-view

Comment: I want to add a view like 0,1,2,3 --view--4,5,6,7--view--8,9,10,11--view--So on where 0 ,1,2,3 is the position of the list items.

Comment: in my answer, the bold number is the position where you need to display a view

Comment: After implementing your code the output is = 0,1,23,4 -view-5,6,7,8,9-view

Comment: But thanks when I changed (position+1)% 4==0 it works Thanks alot.

Comment: @Nancythakkar I still don't know why `(position+1)% 4==0` work, if you using that, your view will display after 3 item

Comment: it shows 0,1,2,3-view-4,5,6,7-view,8,9,10,11-view where 0,1,2,3... position of the list items.

Comment: I forgot when your case is view is not an item of listview. If your view is an item of the listview, you can use my method ;). Thank you for correct me

Comment: Thanks to you for suggestion:)